# SAS- how to concat 2 numerical values onto variable name during while loop

Tags: string, sas, append, concatenation, numeric

I am trying to improve some SAS code by writing a loop to bypass a load of statements. An example of the code block of statements are as follows:

```
if rpq_stage_date_01 ne . then stage_date_01 = rpq_stage_date_01; 
if gps_stage_date_01 ne . then stage_date_01 = gps_stage_date_01;
if ldr_stage_date_01 ne . then stage_date_01 = ldr_stage_date_01; 

if rpq_stage_date_02 ne . then stage_date_02 = rpq_stage_date_02; 
if gps_stage_date_02 ne . then stage_date_02 = gps_stage_date_02;
if ldr_stage_date_02 ne . then stage_date_02 = ldr_stage_date_02;
```

It goes on like this for 14 lines...

So instead of these statements I thought I could make a while loop to iterate over the first 9 numbers and insert/concat a 0 in front of them. 
Unfortunately the zero is necessary.

```
   data test(drop=i);
   num = 0;

   do i=1 to 10; 
       if rpq_stage_date_(num||i) ne . then stage_date_(num||i) = 
   rpq_stage_date_(num||i);

       if gps_stage_date_(num||i) ne . then stage_date_(num||i) = 
   gps_stage_date_(num||i);

       if ldr_stage_date_(num||i) ne . then stage_date_(num||i) = 
   ldr_stage_date_(num||i);


   end; 

   do i = 10 to 14;
       if rpq_stage_date_(i) ne . then stage_date_(i) = rpq_stage_date_(i);
   end;
       if gps_stage_date_(i) ne . then stage_date_(i) = gps_stage_date_(i);
   end;
       if ldr_stage_date_(i) ne . then stage_date_(i) = ldr_stage_date_(i);
   end;

   RUN;
   PROC PRINT data=test; run;
```

I have tried a few different things e.g. cat, catx, the '||' operator. In python this would be very fun to implement but SAS is proving a bit less flexible for my green SAS self. Does anyone even use SAS anymore? I am intrigued!

Any help is greatly appreciated! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
if rpq_stage_date_01 ne . then stage_date_01 = rpq_stage_date_01; 
if gps_stage_date_01 ne . then stage_date_01 = gps_stage_date_01;
if ldr_stage_date_01 ne . then stage_date_01 = ldr_stage_date_01;
```

Can be replaced with

```
stage_date_01 = coalesce(ldr_stage_date_01,gps_stage_date_01,rpq_stage_date_01);
```

You can define arrays to process this with one pass over the array.

```
Array RPQ[*] RPT_STAGE_DATE:;
array gps[*] gps_stage_date:;
array ldr[*] ldr_stage_date:;
array stg[*] stage_date_01-stage_date_10;
do I = 1 to dim(stg);
   stg[i] = coalesce(ldr[I],gps[I],rpq[I]);
   end;
```

Comment: Thank you :) Coalesce is a nifty little function